# Possible to harm app with appsecret?

Tags: facebook

I searched a lot but I can't find simillar question... So, I need to ask you one question about Facebook apps. If someone steal my appsecret (IT IS POSSIBLE) can they do anything with it? Example delete app or change something and how?

Answer (score 0):

With client_id and client_secret, one can use the administrative api to change all aspects of the application. So don't share it.